# Poor UX styling (big spacings, paddings etc.) in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, user-experience

I am currently playing with latest Sitecore, just downloaded from SDN. The first, but quite annoying "feature" in new metro-like interface seems to be huge UX elements, big paddings in content tree between elements (it also quite ugly in Templates Builder). Also just restored a package of my existing solution (taken from 7.2) and I find it very inconvenient to use, as the one is quite big with many items.

Is there any way to switch it back to previous interface? Am also quite worrying about adapting our business users as I spent much time on justifying version upgrade and this type of people do usually judge by what they see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clearly understand your feelings as I had exactly the same first impression.
I dont think there is some switch to return to previous UI.

Nevertheless, it is all about themes. Default theme that is located at **sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\Default** folder, so playing enough with developer tools or firebug you may produce any look-and-feel you want.

I have adjusted Sitecore 8 styles in order to fit both my visual expectations and general good look. To make it simple, I have created the module that replaces those dodgy styles with properly adjusted, to make it look similar to Sitecore 7.

Please read the blog post describing how to implement that; there also will be download link to that package:

http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/is-that-possible-to-cure-sitecore-8-styles-megalomania

The module replaces following style files from folder mentioned above:

```
Content Manager.css 
Default.css 
GlobalHeader.css
Ribbon.css
Shell.css
Startbar.css
Windows.css
Workbox.css
```

Hope this helps!

**Update**: Thank you for inspiring me with an idea of switch. I think it may make sense of implementing a SPEAK component, that allow to switch between conservative and new styles.